# Why is redirect()->back(); function keeps going to login page?

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, redirect, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to set up a multi-language web app. Using a locale switcher middleware, i want to set the locale using an Http request like "locale/ru". Then return to current page as locale session variable set.
(I also have a standard laravel Auth set up for backend control panel.)
But when the request is made (via a url or something like that) laravel redirects me to auth login page like i'm trying to reach a page which requires authentication. 
If i try to make that session setting Http request as an already logged in user, then it redirects me to my default "You're logged in" dashboard page.

If i replace redirect->back() to redirect->route('landing'); then it works but i don't want to set a constant page for this function.
I tried to delete Auth::routes(); from Web Routes, i'm redirected to current page locale session variable set correctly, but i lost laravel authentication abilities.

My LanguageSwitcher middleware code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SwitchLanguage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        //Language switcher
        if(\Session::has('locale'))
        {
            \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        }
        //Language switcher ending!!

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My web routes:

```
<?php


// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('front.anasayfa');
// });

//Language switcher
    Route::get('locale/{locale}', function($locale){
        Session::put('locale',$locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    });

    Route::get('/','AnasayfaController@index')->name('landing');

    Route::get('/haberler','NewsController@index');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

I want to select a language via a url like "locale/etc...." then redirect to current page without interfering with laravel auth.

Comment: try to print `url()->previous()` on `locale/{locale}` route to check if it appears or not

Comment: Thanks, i've tried and it returned "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login". I don't understand why is the previous page sets as login?

Comment: let's try printing `$request->session()->all()`

Comment: Printed $request->session()->all(). It returned an array with 4 items (skipping _token and _flash). _previous item has a "url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000", and my 'locale" session variable holds my session data ("ru" in this case)

Comment: UPDATE: I realized that this only happens on Safari browser. On Chrome and Firefox this doesn't happen. I've cleared Safari cache, deleted history. No avail so far.